# Pandas: conditional dataframe splitting in regular periods

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe where there is a datetime column indicating the beginning of a certain condition (A,B, or C), the value associated to that condition (value) and a counter equal to the sum of minutes between the beginning and the end of the condition.
It looks like this:

```
        date                 Value    Condition count
0   2018-05-01 06:29:00 0.0                 A   1
1   2018-05-01 06:30:00 0.2116250035663446  A   2
2   2018-05-01 06:31:00 2.5572083791097007  A   3
3   2018-05-01 06:32:00 3.4874167144298553  A   4
4   2018-05-01 06:33:00 3.542041709025701   A   5
5   2018-05-01 06:34:00 3.517166723807653   A   6
6   2018-05-01 06:35:00 3.9571250875790915  A   7
7   2018-05-01 06:36:00 5.0706249078114825  B   1
8   2018-05-01 06:37:00 5.062458336353302   B   2
9   2018-05-01 06:38:00 5.051083226998647   B   3
10  2018-05-01 06:39:00 5.049999952316284   B   4
11  2018-05-01 06:40:00 5.061791678269704   B   5
12  2018-05-01 06:41:00 5.025291681289673   B   6
13  2018-05-01 06:42:00 5.065833310286204   B   7
14  2018-05-01 06:43:00 5.051874856154124   B   8
15  2018-05-01 06:44:00 5.073999881744385   B   9
16  2018-05-01 06:45:00 5.04304164648056    B   10
17  2018-05-01 06:46:00 5.090916752815247   B   11
18  2018-05-01 06:47:00 5.045083403587341   B   12
19  2018-05-01 06:48:00 5.036874949932098   B   13
20  2018-05-01 06:49:00 5.047999858856201   B   14
21  2018-05-01 06:50:00 5.048500041166942   B   15
22  2018-05-01 06:51:00 5.031458218892415   B   16
23  2018-05-01 06:52:00 5.036749978860219   B   17
24  2018-05-01 06:53:00 5.057374894618988   B   18
25  2018-05-01 06:54:00 5.065375049908956   B   19
26  2018-05-01 06:55:00 5.101583381493886   B   20
27  2018-05-01 06:56:00 5.064416746298472   B   21
28  2018-05-01 06:57:00 5.0727916558583575  B   22
29  2018-05-01 06:58:00 5.059083342552185   B   23
30  2018-05-01 06:59:00 5.067666749159495   B   24
31  2018-05-01 07:00:00 5.063124974568685   B   25
32  2018-05-01 07:01:00 5.068083385626475   B   26
33  2018-05-01 07:02:00 5.06870836019516    B   27
34  2018-05-01 07:03:00 5.083666622638702   B   28
35  2018-05-01 07:04:00 5.065375069777171   B   29
36  2018-05-01 07:05:00 5.0842918157577515  B   30
37  2018-05-01 07:06:00 5.097625096638997   B   31
38  2018-05-01 07:07:00 5.09241662422816    B   32
39  2018-05-01 07:08:00 5.08754175901413    B   33
40  2018-05-01 07:09:00 5.103041609128316   B   34
41  2018-05-01 07:10:00 5.109624902407329   B   35
42  2018-05-01 07:11:00 5.1207083861033125  B   36
43  2018-05-01 07:12:00 5.086249967416127   B   37
44  2018-05-01 07:13:00 5.079916596412659   B   38
45  2018-05-01 07:14:00 5.088000039259593   B   39
46  2018-05-01 07:15:00 5.087249954541524   B   40
47  2018-05-01 07:16:00 5.0951666831970215  B   41
48  2018-05-01 07:17:00 5.114208340644836   B   42
49  2018-05-01 07:18:00 5.067541758219401   B   43
50  2018-05-01 07:19:00 5.110625088214874   B   44
51  2018-05-01 07:20:00 5.109249929587047   B   45
52  2018-05-01 07:21:00 5.087249894936879   B   46
53  2018-05-01 07:22:00 5.045874913533528   B   47
54  2018-05-01 07:23:00 5.086249927679698   B   48
55  2018-05-01 07:24:00 5.059500118096669   B   49
56  2018-05-01 07:25:00 5.069208304087321   B   50
57  2018-05-01 07:26:00 5.087166567643483   B   51
58  2018-05-01 07:27:00 5.075041770935059   B   52
59  2018-05-01 07:28:00 5.061083436012268   B   53
60  2018-05-01 07:29:00 5.063208381334941   B   54
61  2018-05-01 07:30:00 5.077500065167745   B   55
62  2018-05-01 07:31:00 5.126583437124888   B   56
63  2018-05-01 07:32:00 5.124833265940349   B   57
64  2018-05-01 07:33:00 5.097416520118713   B   58
65  2018-05-01 07:34:00 5.119541605313619   B   59
66  2018-05-01 07:35:00 5.110541661580403   B   60
67  2018-05-01 07:36:00 5.094541708628337   B   61
68  2018-05-01 07:37:00 5.109583298365275   B   62
69  2018-05-01 07:38:00 5.1282082597414655  B   63
70  2018-05-01 07:39:00 5.142249921957652   B   64
71  2018-05-01 07:40:00 5.123124837875366   B   65
72  2018-05-01 07:41:00 5.1302082141240435  B   66
73  2018-05-01 07:42:00 5.128333310286204   B   67
74  2018-05-01 07:43:00 5.143583277861278   B   68
75  2018-05-01 07:44:00 5.089958409468333   B   69
76  2018-05-01 07:45:00 5.095583299795787   B   70
77  2018-05-01 07:46:00 5.106916705767314   B   71
78  2018-05-01 07:47:00 5.073291818300883   B   72
79  2018-05-01 07:48:00 5.058124879995982   B   73
80  2018-05-01 07:49:00 5.112416744232178   B   74
81  2018-05-01 07:50:00 5.091583430767059   B   75
82  2018-05-01 07:51:00 5.130833327770233   B   76
83  2018-05-01 07:52:00 5.09779167175293    B   77
84  2018-05-01 07:53:00 5.1314165989557905  B   78
85  2018-05-01 07:54:00 5.09737503528595    B   79
86  2018-05-01 07:55:00 5.0869999925295515  B   80
87  2018-05-01 07:56:00 5.119083384672801   B   81
88  2018-05-01 07:57:00 5.140083213647206   B   82
89  2018-05-01 07:58:00 5.148874938488007   B   83
90  2018-05-01 07:59:00 5.152333398660024   B   84
91  2018-05-01 08:00:00 5.179041842619578   B   85
92  2018-05-01 08:01:00 5.135874966780345   C   1
93  2018-05-01 08:02:00 4.776458283265431   C   1
94  2018-05-01 08:03:00 2.728124996026357   C   2
95  2018-05-01 08:04:00 0.3433749976490314  C   3
96  2018-05-01 08:05:00 0.0 C   4
97  2018-05-01 08:06:00 0.0 C   5
98  2018-05-01 08:07:00 0.0 C   6
99  2018-05-01 06:29:00 0.0012916666455566883   A   1
100 2018-05-01 06:30:00 0.3798333345912397  A   2
101 2018-05-01 06:31:00 2.1624999741713204  A   3
102 2018-05-01 06:32:00 2.9485416412353516  A   4
103 2018-05-01 06:33:00 2.9937082628409066  A   5
104 2018-05-01 06:34:00 3.0695832868417106  A   6
105 2018-05-01 06:35:00 3.160500019788742   A   7
106 2018-05-01 06:36:00 3.0233334004879 A   8
107 2018-05-01 06:37:00 3.014624993006388   A   9
108 2018-05-01 06:38:00 2.9965833524862924  B   1
109 2018-05-01 06:39:00 3.014708320299784   B   2
110 2018-05-01 06:40:00 2.9999999602635703  B   3
111 2018-05-01 06:41:00 2.9898332953453064  B   4
112 2018-05-01 06:42:00 3.025416682163874   B   5
113 2018-05-01 06:43:00 3.0375834008057914  B   6
114 2018-05-01 06:44:00 3.024541676044464   B   7
115 2018-05-01 06:45:00 3.0192916095256805  B   8
116 2018-05-01 06:46:00 3.0326666633288064  B   9
117 2018-05-01 06:47:00 3.0310416519641876  B   10
118 2018-05-01 06:48:00 3.02166677514712    B   11
119 2018-05-01 06:49:00 3.0129166742165885  B   12
120 2018-05-01 06:50:00 3.0137916107972464  B   13
121 2018-05-01 06:51:00 3.013291676839193   B   14
122 2018-05-01 06:52:00 3.0225417017936707  B   15
123 2018-05-01 06:53:00 3.0179584125677743  B   16
124 2018-05-01 06:54:00 3.018083373705546   B   17
125 2018-05-01 06:55:00 3.0191250145435333  B   18
126 2018-05-01 06:56:00 3.0106250643730164  B   19
127 2018-05-01 06:57:00 3.005666603644689   B   20
128 2018-05-01 06:58:00 3.003083348274231   B   21
129 2018-05-01 06:59:00 3.0044583280881247  B   22
130 2018-05-01 07:00:00 2.9925417304039 B   23
131 2018-05-01 07:01:00 2.997625013192495   B   24
132 2018-05-01 07:02:00 3.00687504808108    B   25
133 2018-05-01 07:03:00 2.993708292643229   B   26
134 2018-05-01 07:04:00 2.9989166955153146  B   27
135 2018-05-01 07:05:00 3.0079166889190674  B   28
136 2018-05-01 07:06:00 2.990499963363012   B   29
137 2018-05-01 07:07:00 3.0224166214466095  B   30
138 2018-05-01 07:08:00 3.022499988476435   B   31
139 2018-05-01 07:09:00 3.041124939918518   B   32
140 2018-05-01 07:10:00 3.0160833597183228  B   33
141 2018-05-01 07:11:00 3.0267500281333923  B   34
142 2018-05-01 07:12:00 3.028375039498011   B   35
143 2018-05-01 07:13:00 3.0230000019073486  B   36
144 2018-05-01 07:14:00 3.0227500398953757  B   37
145 2018-05-01 07:15:00 3.0183333853880563  B   38
146 2018-05-01 07:16:00 3.0084999799728394  B   39
147 2018-05-01 07:17:00 3.037958323955536   B   40
148 2018-05-01 07:18:00 3.0259583592414856  B   41
149 2018-05-01 07:19:00 3.0275417367617288  B   42
150 2018-05-01 07:20:00 3.043500026067098   B   43
151 2018-05-01 07:21:00 3.024250010649363   B   44
152 2018-05-01 07:22:00 3.0122083127498627  B   45
153 2018-05-01 07:23:00 3.034375081459681   B   46
154 2018-05-01 07:24:00 3.023208330074946   B   47
155 2018-05-01 07:25:00 3.031499981880188   B   48
156 2018-05-01 07:26:00 3.0316666960716248  B   49
157 2018-05-01 07:27:00 3.0248333513736725  B   50
158 2018-05-01 07:28:00 3.019208381573359   B   51
159 2018-05-01 07:29:00 3.0272917052110038  B   52
160 2018-05-01 07:30:00 3.0311250189940133  B   53
161 2018-05-01 07:31:00 3.0278749962647757  B   54
162 2018-05-01 07:32:00 3.026416619618734   B   55
163 2018-05-01 07:33:00 3.0073334177335105  B   56
164 2018-05-01 07:34:00 3.0283333361148834  B   57
165 2018-05-01 07:35:00 3.0268333156903586  B   58
166 2018-05-01 07:36:00 3.0359583099683127  B   59
167 2018-05-01 07:37:00 3.0310832361380258  B   60
168 2018-05-01 07:38:00 3.0232499639193215  B   61
169 2018-05-01 07:39:00 3.0258750120798745  B   62
170 2018-05-01 07:40:00 3.048666755358378   B   63
171 2018-05-01 07:41:00 3.0416250129540763  B   64
172 2018-05-01 07:42:00 3.0280833343664804  B   65
173 2018-05-01 07:43:00 3.0271250307559967  B   66
174 2018-05-01 07:44:00 3.0204999844233194  B   67
175 2018-05-01 07:45:00 3.0249999463558197  B   68
176 2018-05-01 07:46:00 3.0264166494210563  B   69
177 2018-05-01 07:47:00 3.0191666384538016  B   70
178 2018-05-01 07:48:00 3.03249990940094    B   71
179 2018-05-01 07:49:00 3.04025000333786    B   72
180 2018-05-01 07:50:00 3.0262083609898887  B   73
181 2018-05-01 07:51:00 3.0421666502952576  B   74
182 2018-05-01 07:52:00 3.026083320379257   B   75
183 2018-05-01 07:53:00 3.015916734933853   B   76
184 2018-05-01 07:54:00 3.037125051021576   B   77
185 2018-05-01 07:55:00 3.0373750229676566  B   78
186 2018-05-01 07:56:00 3.029458353916804   B   79
187 2018-05-01 07:57:00 3.0207917292912803  B   80
188 2018-05-01 07:58:00 3.0240416824817657  B   81
189 2018-05-01 07:59:00 3.0232083996136985  B   82
190 2018-05-01 08:00:00 3.027666707833608   B   83
191 2018-05-01 08:01:00 3.020083318154017   C   1
192 2018-05-01 08:02:00 3.0192916889985404  C   1
193 2018-05-01 08:03:00 1.9129582916696866  C   2
194 2018-05-01 08:04:00 0.25358333881013095 C   3
195 2018-05-01 08:05:00 0.0 C   4
196 2018-05-01 08:06:00 0.0 C   5
197 2018-05-01 08:07:00 0.0 C   6
198 2018-05-01 08:08:00 0.0 C   7
199 2018-05-01 08:09:00 0.0 C   8
```

I would like to split into smaller group just the condition B, in order to have it divided each 30min, starting from the first rounded hour, ending the division at the last rounded hour, and summing the values of the corresponding sub-periods. The other conditions A,C grouped without this sub-division, but still maintaining the order they are.

It would look something like:

```
date                      condition        count        value      
01,01,2018 06:29             A               7           17
01,01,2018 06:36             B               24          101
01,01,2018 07:00             B               30          250
01,01,2018 07:30             B               30          272
01,01,2018 08:00             B               30          300
01,01,2018 08:01             B               1           4
01,01,2018 08:02             C               8           12
01,01,2018 06:30             A               8           17
01,01,2018 06:38             B               22          101
01,01,2018 07:00             B               30          250
01,01,2018 07:30             B               30          272
01,01,2018 08:00             B               30          300
01,01,2018 08:01             C               8           12
```

Note that, at the end of the first sub-division, the end time is not a rounded hour, so the remaining part (1 minute, from 8:01 to 8:01) is another sub-group. Maybe I should have done this before the initial grouping.
Any idea? thank you for your time!

Comment: You're going to have to provide the minute-granularity dataframe. You can't go from the input you've displayed to the output you've displayed.

Comment: yes, you are right. The reason I didn't is that I should have written around 200 rows. But something similar, in a reduced version, can be seen in the link I put (there, the value column is missing because it was not relevant for that question).

Comment: Personally, I'd rather see 200 rows than an example I can't copy/paste into my editor and test. You're putting a lot of burden on the answerer to make up data. Most answerers want to test their solution before posting, since incorrect solutions are liable to get downvoted. Tbh, I (personally) just don't have all day. I try to answer these questions as quickly as possible, and if I can't do that, I just move on. Other answerers are different, but I think there are a lot like me. You'll get an answer faster if you give an "input" vs "output" type of question

Comment: Ok, understood, thank you for the advice! I thought it was worse to have so many data :) but now I know and I've updated the question.

Comment: Your data looks kind of odd. For example, there are two entries at time `2018-05-01 06:42:00`, rows 13 and 112, but they have different counts/values. It's hard to group by time intervals if the times are not distinct. Are you sure the input data is correct? Should row 112 be on the next day (`2018-05-02`)?

Comment: yes it's complicated, but it's correct. It's like this because events can occur at the same time.

Comment: At the moment my idea is to create 2 df, one including just A and C and one where I create a new column in B called "half hour", that identifies the different slices of 30minutes time: 
`d2['half_hour']=d2['date'].map(lambda x: x-datetime.timedelta(minutes=x.minute-((x.minute/30)*30)))`

Then, I will merge them...let's see if it works